# How to put logo in left, and text vertically-aligned next to it?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

In my header, I want my logo to the left, and text to the right of it:

1. If there's enough space, text should be in one line vertically-align to the middle.
2. If there isn't, text should reflow to 2 lines, preferably aligned to the middle as well.

I can satisfy (1) with the below code. But once I reduce the width of the whole page, the `h1` is displayed below the `img`. If I remove the `h1 {display:inline-block}`, then the `h1` is displayed correctly to the left of the `img` - but then the `vertical-align` dosn't take effect.

How can I achieve both?

```
<img src="http://test.tipulnagish.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/tick-1015459_640.png">
<div>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
</div>

img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
    float: left;
}
div {
    height: 130px;
    line-height: 130px;
}
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jobarner/4mzj50sx/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/4mzj50sx/6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="div">
    <img src="http://test.tipulnagish.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/tick-1015459_640.png">
    <div>
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div {
    display: table;
}

div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Yes! I guess only `display:table` does the right thing here

Answer (score 1):

You do not need tables to line something up....

Just use inline-block to line the divs up, and then use a before element to center the text in the right div with...

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/46xqLngb/

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="left">
  <img src="http://test.tipulnagish.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/tick-1015459_640.png">
      </div>
  <div class="right">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
  </div>
</div>


img {
    height: 100px;
}
div.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
}
div.left {
    width: 13%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height:100%;
}
div.right {
    width: 83%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
}
h1 {
    line-height: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
h1:before {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: could you explain the h1:before part ?

Comment: Absolutely!

So, if you vertically align something in that right container, the dom has no idea what it is aligning to(pretty misleading if you ask me), so...
We make a before element to inline-block align it to (give it a height of 100% and a width of 0).

This lets the dom know what it needs to align to the middle of.

So, in short, you just give the element a before element of 100%, so the DOM knows what it needs to align to the middle of.

Comment: If you change the width to a couple px and the color to not white.. then you will see it in action. 

It is how everyone at my work aligns things vertically.

Comment: i thought it would try to align it relative to it's parent. That was very use full piece of info thanks.

Comment: Doesn'y work right - when text wraps, it does so under the logo.

Comment: The question was how to vertical align it... That worked

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Part

```
<div class="mainHeader">
    <img src="http://test.tipulnagish.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/tick-1015459_640.png" class="img"/>
    <p class="textStyle">WOW</p>
</div>
```

The CSS Part:

```
.mainHeader{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%
}

.img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
}

.textStyle {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

I guess this helps You

Comment: Doesn't work right - if width for text is not enough, the whole text goes under the logo.